# i am getting an servlet exception(TIBCO EBX)

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, tibco

the UI shows this

`ServletException when including resource /Services/validation/ExportRapportValidationFromPerspective.jsp of web application axa-common, original exception is: null`

log shows

2024-01-25 11:44:27,854 CET ERROR  log.kernel 1216:0002 [https-jsse-nio-100.112.118.134-8443-exec-2]  10.187.17.90    ...782312D5080642F7D:2  ebx-manager P   .sessionIn.data_root.data_main  wbp:_Manager.html  U   initialHybrid   UAssetCentralTeam   ServletException when including or forwarding to resource /Services/validation/ExportRapportValidationFromPerspective.jsp of web application axa-common

> below are the code

```
\`\<%@page import="com.orchestranetworks.ui.UICSSClasses"%\>
\<%@page import="fr.axa.ebx.common.validation.RapportValidation"%\>
\<%@page import="java.io.File"%\>
\<%@page import="com.onwbp.adaptation.Adaptation"%\>
\<%@page import="com.onwbp.adaptation.AdaptationHome"%\>
\<%@include file="../header.jsp"%\>

\<%
String thisJsp = "/Services/validation/ExportRapportValidationFromPerspective.jsp";
Boolean isInPerspective = true;
String dataSet = request.getParameter("dataSet");
String dataSpace = request.getParameter("branch");
String endingUrl = RapportValidation.getUrlForEndingService(ServiceContext.getServiceContext(request), isInPerspective);
%\>

\<%
// Lancement de l'export avec icon waiter
if (request.getParameter("doExport") == null && request.getParameter("exportDone") == null) {
%\>

        " style="position: relative; top: -50%; height: 32px;"\>&nbsp;
    
    
    
    
    window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('exportIFrame').src='<%=sContext.getURLForIncludingResource(thisJsp)%>&doExport=true&isInPerspective=<%=isInPerspective%>&dataSet=<%=dataSet%>&branch=<%=dataSpace%>';", 500);

\<%
//Inside the iframe, export execution
} else if (request.getParameter("doExport") != null) {

                new RapportValidation(request, response, thisJsp, isInPerspective, dataSpace, dataSet).generateErrorFile();
    
                //Affichage du résultat
            } else {
                String home = request.getParameter("dataspaceId");
                String instance = request.getParameter("instanceId");
                String dateExport = request.getParameter("dateExport");
                String finalFilename;
                if (instance == null) {
                    // dataspace export
                    finalFilename = "ValidationReport_Home_" + home + "_" + dateExport + ".csv";
```

> else {

> ```
>               finalFilename = "ValidationReport_" + instance + "_" + dateExport + ".csv";
>               }
>               File exportedFile = (File) sContext.getSession().getAttribute("exportedFile");
>               sContext.getSession().setAttribute("exportedFile", null);
>
> %\>
>
> "\>
>
> > <p>">
> > 
> > </p>
> >
> >     <a>" href="#"
> >         onClick="document.getElementById('exportIFrame').src='<%=sContext.getURLForIncludingResource(thisJsp)%>&doExport=true&isInPerspective=<%=isInPerspective%>&dataSet=<%=dataSet%>&branch=<%=dataSpace%>';"> If the
> >         download doesn't start automatically click here. </a> <br> <br> <br> <input class="ebx_Button" type="submit"
> >         onclick="document.location.href='<%=endingUrl%>'; return false;" value="Close" />
>
>     window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('exportIFrame').src='<%=urlWebapp%>/download?file=<%=exportedFile.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/")%>&finalName=<%=finalFilename%>&isInPerspective=<%=isInPerspective%>&dataSet=<%=dataSet%>&branch=<%=dataSpace%>';",500);
>
> \<%
> }
>
> > > %\>\`
> ```